# mousePressed in a loop

Tags: processing

can anyone tell me how to use a mousePressed in a loop
when I click on each square it changes the color one at a time.

```java
int WIDTH = 200; 
int HEIGHT = 200;
int X = WIDTH /3; 
int Y = HEIGHT / 4;

void setup()
{
    size(200,200); 
    background(255);
    strokeWeight(4);
    stroke(2);
}

void draw()
{
    for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) { 
        for (int g = 0; g < 4; g++) { 
            if ((n + g + 1) % 2 == 0) {
            }
            fill(255);
            rect(n * X, g * Y, (n + 1) * X, (g + 1) * Y); 
        }
    }
}
void mousePressed() {}
```

Comment: https://processing.org/reference/mousePressed_.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Store the **state** of your squares in some kind of data structure. You might use a 2D array of `boolean` values for this.

**Step 2:** Map the data structure to the positions of squares. If you have a 2D array, you might map index `[i][j]` to an `x,y` position of `i*50, j*50`. This is just an example, and the values you use depend on how large you want your squares to be.

**Step 3:** In the `mousePressed()` function, go the other way: given the `mouseX, mouseY` position of the cursor, map that back to an `[i][j]` index in your 2D array. Set the state of that index (for example, flip the `boolean` value at that index).

**Step 4:** In the `draw()` function, iterate over your 2D array and draw a square (using the same coordinate mapping from step 2) based on the value at that index.